# nodejs mongodb native driver not display docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

There is something wrong with the code below?

Yesterday with the same code, returning me the result with the docs, today it does not work .....

Is there a better way to write this code?

```
var mongodb     = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient,
    url         = 'mongodb://localhost/api';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection established to', url);
        db.close();
    }
});

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/api', function(err, db) {
        console.log(db);
        var collection = db.collection(req.params.section);
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
        db.close();
    });
};
```

Comment: So what is the error you get, or do you net get an error at all?

Comment: As far as "a better way", don't open and close your connection pool on each request. Just open it once and leave it open for the life of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this [page](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html), you close the `db` before the `find` return the result in your codes, please try to put `db.close()` into the callback of `find`

```
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        res.send(items);
        db.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the asynchronous nature of your the database, it looks like you are closing the database before the query has returned the documents.  This is a race condition and it may perform differently depending on the order of events.  You must ensure that you have completed the find query before closing the db.

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
    res.send(items);
    db.close();
});
```

This way you are closing the database in the callback, which only executes when the query is completed.